# Can I perform the same functionality as this loop in sql?

Tags: coldfusion, sql-server-2016

What I'm doing is checking for a gap between several dates, and calling the result a duplicate if there is not a 14 day gap from the last non-duplicate result.

The code looks like this in coldfusion:

```
<cfset date_check = data.date_to_check />
    <cfset counted = 1 />
    <cfloop query="data" > 

        #dateformat( date_to_check )# <br> 

        <cfif abs( dateDiff('d', date_check , data.date_to_check ) ) gt 14 > 
            <cfset counted ++ />
            <cfset date_check = data.date_to_check />
            Not Duplicate
        <cfelseif currentrow gt 1> 
            Duplicate
        <cfelse> 
            Not Duplicate
        </cfif>

    </cfloop>

    > #counted#
```

And the output, for example will be:

```
19-Jan-18 Not Duplicate
16-Jan-18 Duplicate
21-Oct-16 Not Duplicate
12-Oct-16 Duplicate
06-Oct-16 Not Duplicate
22-Sep-16 Duplicate
09-Aug-16 Not Duplicate
11-Jul-16 Not Duplicate
> 5
```

I tried using outer apply and joining the next row that is 14 days from the current row. But the problem with this approach is if I have a cluster, it "resets" the date each row, like this:

```
19-Jan-18 - not duplicate
16-Jan-18 - duplicate 
10-Jan-18 - will give false duplicate ( compares itself to Jan 16 instead of Jan 19 )
```

The query for this is something like this:

```
SELECT 
    count(*)
FROM @item T1
    OUTER APPLY ( 
        SELECT TOP 1 * 
        FROM @item T2 
        WHERE T2.[index] < T1.[index]  
        ORDER BY T2.[index] DESC) T
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, T.[date], T1.[date])  > 14
```

Comment: This seems to be a Gaps and Islands SQL problem more than a ColdFusion problem. It'll probably be a lot easier to solve in SQL. Especially 2016. And this also seems like it might benefit from a Calendar Table / Date Dimension. But this seems like it may be an X-Y Problem. Does your application NEED to know which ones are duplicates, or does it only care to compare between non-duplicates?

Comment: @Shawn I included the coldfusion solution (which does give correct results) for reference only because it's the way I currently perform the calculation. And the only part of the answer I actually need is a count of non-duplicates, which would be grouped by a third column that I didn't include in the question. Because the data I'm working with is quite static, I don't actually have any need to change it to sql, but asked solely out of curiousity as to whether or not it could be done.

Answer (score 2):

I think an EXISTS subquery would be the most straightforward way to do it. If that isn't performant enough, then you could do a join for it, but I find that EXISTS is generally fast enough and much easier to read.

```
 SELECT     ID,
            Name,
            Date_To_Check,
            CASE
                WHEN        EXISTS (
                                SELECT  1
                                FROM    Table1 b
                                WHERE   b.Date_To_Check < a.Date_To_Check
                                    AND DATEDIFF(d,b.Date_To_Check,a.Date_To_Check) <= 14
                            )
                    THEN    1
                ELSE        0
            END AS isDuplicate
 FROM       Table1 AS a
```